# Turn off auto-completion/company while in org-journal

Tags: hooks, auto-complete-mode, org-journal

Trying to get org-journal working, but it wants to auto-complete nearly every word I type, then require two space bar hits to advance to type next word.

I tried this and it works

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (toggle-auto-completion-off)))
```

but this is a false-friend and causes bizarre problems other places. I want company on but just not while typing text in org-journal. Can that be done?

Here is my org-journal config

```
(use-package org-journal
  :after org
  :custom
  (org-journal-dir "~/Dropbox/org/journal/")
  (org-journal-date-prefix "#+TITLE: ")
  (org-journal-time-prefix "* ")
  (org-journal-file-format "%Y/%m/%Y%m%d.org")
  (org-journal-date-format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
  (org-journal-enable-agenda-integration t)
  :bind
  ("C-c j" . org-journal-new-entry))
```

Yes, when I disable company, the problem goes away. A hook should allow this, but I'm getting it wrong?

```
(add-hook 'org-journal-mode-hook (company-mode -1))
```

Comment: That should be `(add-hook 'org-journal-mode-hook (lambda () (company-mode -1)))`.  Hooks are lists of functions not forms.

Comment: Yes, I think I tried it but it didn't seem to work -- or I don't know how or where to apply it. Where would it go?

Comment: Put it in the `use-package` stanza after `:config`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked in the org-journal block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the suggestion of Fran Burstall above in the comments, I added a properly written hook to `org-journal-mode-hook` to my org-journal `use-package` block

```
(use-package org-journal
  :after org
  :custom
  (org-journal-dir "~/Dropbox/org/journal/")
  (org-journal-date-prefix "#+TITLE: ")
  (org-journal-time-prefix "* ")
  (org-journal-file-format "%Y/%m/%Y%m%d.org")
  (org-journal-date-format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
  (org-journal-enable-agenda-integration t)
  :bind
  ("C-c j" . org-journal-new-entry)
  :config
  (add-hook 'org-journal-mode-hook (lambda () (company-mode -1))))
```